# Creating a full business website

Tags: plugins, user-registration, web-services

I have a webservice and I want to sell it and allow the customer to set it up through a website. I'm thinking to use WordPress to make this website, but don't know if it is possible or how to do it.

Basically, my webservice needs some information from the customer to work. I mean, after buying our service, the customer will have access to a page and he/she will input some information and submit them (to our server, that will set up the service for that customer). I need the WordPress to save these input information and display them later, whenever the customer access and log-in my website.

In other words, I need any user can:

- Buy my service (public area) and then log-in to set it up (private area)
- Save, update and delete input personal information (that only he/she can see/create/update/delete)

Can I do this through WordPress? Any idea on how?

Comment: Your question is _very_ vague. Please improve it, be specific.

Comment: I guess you'll have to go back to @toscho comment and rework it again. It's still overly broad to answer it with a single answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand you guys. What aren't you understanding at my question? Can't you just tell me what instead of asking me to review my question again and again? I am a common user here, not an expert to make perfect questions... Sorry, but I don't know what I am asking wrong by myself. I'll try to rework it one last time, before I leave this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes but you may need to use a combination of access plugins and custom post types to represent the data that your users are going to enter.

Start with researching custom post types in the WP codex and then research some of the developing plugins to help speed up the process in the area - check out "podCMS" or "Types and Views".

You should also check out the member access / subscription plugins starting with "role scoper" to help with the access.  Just google for "wordpress membership" or "user access control" and you find 20 - 30 options.

I am not sure if this helps but I hope it is a start in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to make website and the easiest way is through word press. Word press is most popular blogging and website creating site; with word press you can build blog, website or both. You do not need any webmaster to handle website. Just one click and you install, configure website and use it for business.
Reason to use word press for your small business website:

1. Content management system: It has very powerful content management system.
2. Easily update content:  If you do not know HTML or editor tool like Dreamweaver so do not worry. Because it is very easy to update content in wordpress without knowledge of HTML, and most of it you do not ask every time to your webmaster to make a small change.
3. Easily create designs and themes: In this you can easily create designs and themes without the help of developer, so no waiting for developer.
4. Install in one click: just one click and you can quick install are provided by many hosting providers, including blueshost.
   Wordpress is new breed of website creator known as CMS (content management system).It is a great program to make a websites or blogs and it comes with your web host plan.

You can browse some great [wordpress plugins](http://www.openwebsitetutorials.com/811/some-popular-plugins-to-take-a-look-at/) on google as I did or you can take help of wordpress tutorials online.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Sandra! I opted to go with a MVC Framework written in PHP (: